# (jQuery Masonry) Corner stamp in fluid layouts does not work?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, fluid-layout

I have found that it does not work.
When `columnWidth: 100,` it works.
When `columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
    return containerWidth / 5;}` 'float' for div 'corner stamp' is not working
[image: jQuery Masonry corner stamp fluid]

Comment: Not sure why you assigning function to columnWidth.. shouldn't it be something like "columnWidth: containerWidth / 5" instead?

Comment: I have taken is with source.  Your method is valid for [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) jQuery.

Comment: May be if you give more code or even better setup JSFiddle it will be easier to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/